# Keras > using trained model on different machine with different python version

Tags: python, linux, windows, tensorflow, keras

I am working on an ML project and use `keras` with `Tensorflow` backed. I need to do the training part on Python 3.5 my local windows machine, save the model, then copy the model to a virtual machine (also running 3.5) on a linux which will use the model for predictions.

Task seems very clear and easy, however I get an error while calling the `predict` function.

```
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("activation_1/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

I thought that it could be a platform difference issue, so I trained my model on a Linux machine (with Python 3.4), but I still get the same error on the predicting virtual machine.

I wonder if the cause of the error is the OS or the Python version difference or perhaps something else? On each platform separately model training, saving then loading and predicting works fine.

Comment: Two questions: 
1. When you say it works on the same machine does that include the model serialization?
2. What are you using (pickle/JSON) to store the model?

actually, 3 questions... what's the entrance layer to your model?

Comment: 1. Yes, I save the model and python session closed. Then from another python session I load it. 2. I use JSON for saving the architecture and h5 for weights. 3. The entrance layer is `Dense` with 256 neurons.

Comment: No idea what could be the problem, should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the problem was in the saving part. I was using `ModelCheckpoint` callback for saving the best model

```
model.fit(..., callbacks = [ModelCheckpoint(filepath='model.h5', save_best_only=True)])
```

After doing some search on the web and trying some different advice I have removed that part and saved the model like this

```
model.save('model.h5')
```

This solved the problem.